# Storing JWT in react context

Tags: reactjs, authentication, jwt, token, single-page-application

Based on this requirement: Users remain logged in only as long as they have their browser open. Is there any recommendation for an SPA to not store JWT tokens in memory?

```
//app.js
const reducer = (state, action = null) => {
    switch (action.type) {
      case "SET_TOKEN":
        return {
          ...state,
          token: action.token,
        };
.............
```

```
//login.js
const token = await login(
          email.value,
          password.value
        );
dispatch({ type: "SET_TOKEN", token });
```

Comment: you can put your token in localStorage, even the browser is closed, the token will be there.

Comment: LocalStorage is not a good practice: https://github.com/OWASP/CheatSheetSeries/blob/master/cheatsheets/HTML5_Security_Cheat_Sheet.md#local-storage

Comment: If you don’t keep sensitive information in token, there is no problem using localStorage

Comment: @SuleymanSah Refresh token in a cookie and access token in memory can be a good model if used with care.